# Use of the phrase: "more severely than"

Tags: grammar

I am having a hard time correcting this scientific quote:

> Both tree carbon acquisition and tree carbon demand decreased more
>   severely if water deficit directly affected tree growth than if it
>   affected indirectly carbon source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both tree carbon acquisition and tree carbon demand decreased more severely if water deficit directly affected tree growth than if it affected its carbon source.

It's assumed that it's indirect, because the carbon source ≠ the tree.

I don't see anything wrong with "more severely" although "more steeply" might be nicer.

Answer (score 1):

*Severe* has a connotation of not just *strong* but *harsh* or *cruel*; so I would not use *severely* to modify *decrease* unless I wanted to imply quite strongly that the decrease was undesirable or even unfair.